# Memorizing the quran

Tags: quran

Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said that the best of the Muslims are those who memorize the quran. What I've been doing is listening to surahs over and over again until I can recite them with the reciter. That has worked for me so far, but now I'm having trouble with yaseen. I'm not going in order. Does anyone have any tips for how to memorize those long surahs?

Comment: first of all,k I am not sure that Allah said that the best are those who memorize the Quran, actually I think you mean what the Prophet {Peace be Upon Him] said that the best are the ones who learn the Quran and teach it, http://sunnah.com/bukhari/66/50  second, this question is a list question, not good for this site.

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.mounthira.com/) service for memorization. I use it from time to time and found it useful (only for memorization). Other than that, make du'a to Allah to help you retain what you have memorized. Other than that, I think this question should be closed

Comment: @evthim: you might find it easier to memorise if you learn arabic :)

Comment: understand them(not just rote learning), break into sections as comfortable, revise as much as possible. No shortcuts, biger the surahs, more difficult it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening again and again is not a way of memorizing, though it may help you memorize short surahs. Longer surahs have to be memorized  by reading again and again. Listening is a great way of revising.

I'd like to share how I memorize the long surahs.

1. First of all stop treating it a long surah. Divide the surah into pages or ruku's, you'll find it shorter.
2. Fix a time of the day for memorizing and follow it daily. The ideal time I would suggest is the time between asr and isha prayers. After fajr is also a great time.
3. For memorizing, use a **hafizi mushaf**.
4. Be in a constant effort to join the divided memorizations as soon as you complete the memorization of a new part.
5. For revising by listening, divide the surah's audio file in the same proportion as you did for memorizing. As an example, you can take a look [**here**](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B7dbPy02FOURX0Rjbk12UWI1dXM/edit), at the parts I have divided Ruku' wise. You can use softwares like **[Blaze](http://www.blazemp.com/)** and **[Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html)** or a free one like **[audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net).** But make sure you don't miss out an ayah. You can use this divided file for revising and listen when you are free or while travelling.
6. Audio is a great way of revising and correcting yourself but it is slow. I recommend you to use the mushaf for revising and use the audio only when you don't have access to the mushaf. As for correcting yourself, visit a Hafiz or the Imaam of your mosque at least once a week.
7. Meanwhile, As @Abdullah suggested, Constantly pray to Allah and seek guidance and his help to memorize and retain the memorized.

As you continue memorizing, you'll develop your own methods and patterns Insha Allah. Do add an answer here if later you realise that you've developed one.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

**Jazaakallah...**

Answer (score -1):

The best online resources are those that can offer you with “ayats” and “surahs” that can help you in gaining a complete and vivid understanding about Quran in no more than a single click. You are supposed to make an effort, in order, to be able to locate a course that will prove to be the useful so as to ensure that you can become competent about Quran. If you are able to search for the right [memorize Quran online course](https://www.tayseerulquran.com/memorize-quran-online.php), you must not face the least difficulty in learning details about different types of Quran topics such as; poetry, Arabic parables, a Hadith and Quranic verses.I hope it will be help you.